# TeamCity + git push becomes unresponsive. Asking for creds maybe?

Tags: git, teamcity

This looks like a common problem here, but I'll give my situation. I am trying to use TeamCity to create new branches.

The command sequence is as follows:

```
git branch %foo%
git checkout %foo%
git push origin %foo%
```

When I run the command, the agent's console tells me that it's switched to the branch designated by %foo% and I've also put in debug statements to prove that that command completes, but the

```
git push origin %foo%
```

command never completes. I've waited several, several minutes for a test project that's less than 300k in size. I have validated that git's origin is correct, among other things. I have even switched the last Git operation to use cmd\git rather than bin\git. No change. I have confirmed that this sequence of commands works on my Mac. When I run the command inside git bash, I'm asked to enter credentials. I also read in one of the

Is it possible that the agent is locking up because git is expecting credentials? If so, how do I successfully pass credentials stored in the VCS step of TeamCity to the git command? If it's something else, what am I doing wrong? I'm a bit stuck here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that the agent is locking up because git is expecting credentials?

yes, that would be a logical explanation.

Make sure you have entered proper credentials (username and password, if you are using an http(s) url) in the [**Authentication Settings**](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Git+%28JetBrains%29#Git%28JetBrains%29-AuthenticationSettings), when configuring the VCS root used by your TeamCity job.

Comment: The repository I'm pushing to is a private repository. My account has 2-factor authentication, so I'm using an API key for authentication; and I'm using this same VCS Root to build the solution on an automated build process in TeamCity. The only permission I've given this key is 'repo'. Is that insufficient? I'm already using this key successfully elsewhere. Do I have to do something special to get permission to do this action in a Command Prompt step?